# Find a string column using both the sum and max in hive sql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

```
create table t(
a string,
b string,
c int,
d int)
```

This table has duplicate a data.
I want to sum(c), sum (d) and order by sum(c)

so I try to this.

```
SELECT a, b, sum(c) as cum, sum(d) FROM t GROUP BY a order by cum DESC
```

I can't run this. Because is b.
So I try to Subqueries but I coundn't
Please help.

Comment: You might want to look into group by, you have two aggregates (`SUM`) and two identifiers, both of these should be in the `GROUP BY` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group by must contain both a & b.

so in your case use the below

```
   SELECT a, b, sum(c) as cum, sum(d) FROM t GROUP BY a,b order by cum DESC
```